# Do Gurukulas and Vedic Patashalas censor sexual topics in the scripture for students who are kids?

Tags: vedas, sex, teaching

The Hindu scriptures, such as the Vedas and Smriti, has lots of topics on sex. My question is, just like how secular people nowadays do, do teachers in the Gurukulas and Vedic patashalas censor such topics for children under the age of 18? And if so, why?

Like for example, here is what the Manusmriti says:

> Persons learned in the Veda and knowing the law declare that for the
>   twice-born person keeping up his vows, **the intentional emission of
>   semen means a ‘transgression of the vow.’**—(120)

Rationally speaking, it makes sense to **not** censor such things, lest they be committing sins.

Comment: For a long time I too wonder how masters teach sexual content in the scriptures. For example read the story of Matsyagandha in Mahabharata.